# Protection Javascript files

Tags: javascript, security, cross-domain

I have a project where I have to host JavaScript files on server A.
The real application is hosted on server B (and has a different domain name).
Is there a clean solution to only allow the domain of server B to access those JavaScript files?
E.g. functionality like allow-from headers for JavaScript or something with .htaccess files.
The servers are PHP servers with an apache in front (so .htaccess solutions are possible as well).

Comment: `.htaccess` is one way ... either way, you wont be able to hide the code in the javascript if this is a browser based "application"

Comment: What are the JS files used for?

Comment: Sure you can require special headers (allow-from or referer) to be in a request. However you should realize that such method only can prevent access to client-side scripts; not access at all. Someone can write a server-side script easily faking all required headers.

Comment: It's a general application to load some management functionality around sport results and being able to click through to details and stuff.
The logic (general JS) is hosted at server B (the real providing company), and it's included within html pages hosted at server A and C (websites of specific sport associations). They now want functionality to be able to exclude A or C if they don't pay their subscriptions